# How to pass 2 complex parameters to ActionResult with AJAX POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action result function in my controller which is called from the client with AJAX POST.  It used to take in only 1 complex parameter and worked fine.  Since I got more requirements coming my way, I now need it to take 2 complex parameters.  With 2 parameters Model Binder seems to fail to serialize the incoming data in the correct way (I'm getting nulls).  What should the incoming parameters look like in their stringified version?

For example:

```
public ActionResult Bla(Person p, Car c)
{}

public class Person
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
}

public class Car
{
  public string Make;
  public string Model;
}
```

I used to send in just 1 stringified JSON object (for example Person).  Now I'm trying to glue together Person and Car into one JSON object.  Is this where I'm going wrong?

I form the JSON object in the following way:

```
var person= {};
person['FirstName'] = 'Bob';
person['LastName'] = 'Jones';
//now same for c
var params = JSON.stringify({ 'p': person, 'c': car});

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/bla',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: params,
//and so on
```

I tried a couple of other ways of constructing these parameters, but they don't seem to work either.

Comment: can u show how u hv formed JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to realy check in firebug for what gets posted:

You want the parameters to look like:

```
person.FirstName
```

If you post objects like

```
 var personData = {
        FirstName: "First",
        LastName: "Last"

    };
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Product/Bla",
        data:  personData 
        })
    });
```

Your parameters look like

```
person[FirstName]
```

An easy way is to change the parameters getting posted with a plugin  from Nick Frost

http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually just got it working like 5 minutes ago. I have no clue what the problem was, since the parameters looked fine in FireBug's console, the property names were matching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them as a json object in 2 different properties(names as defined in the action). 
Something like this, you don't have to `stringify` it just pass it as shown below jQuery will take care of it.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../Controller/bla",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        p: {
           FirstName: "FristName",
           LastName: "LastName"
        },
        c: {
           Make: "Make",
           Model: "Model"
        }
    },
    success: function(){  
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be stringified before executing the AJAX call?

Comment: Not required, jQuery will take care of it.

Comment: Either way it doesn't work. I tried adding/removing quotes around c & p.  Also, no luck.

Comment: @Dimskiy - I have added the `contentType` in my answer try that.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I have plus encoding. Both parameters are coming in as nulls no matter what I do.

Comment: Do you see anything being sent in the console?

Comment: Yes. The console clearly shows the parameters being sent. Either in JSON format or in the form format, depending on what I do with the contentType setting.

Comment: This is MVC3. The Model Binder should take care of serialization "automatically", shouldn't it? I posted my server side ActionResult function in the original post.  There isn't much to it.

Comment: Yes, the Model Binder should take care of it. If the property names match then Model Binder should populate them.

Comment: Yeah I know.  I had similar cases before, when I had to pass in multiple complex parameters.  I do not recall ever running into such a problem.

Comment: Ok! So... I went back to basics, sending 1 parameter. It worked. I then made it take 1 complex parameter, and it worked. I then made it take 2 complex parameters, and it worked. I have it working. I have no clue what the problem was. Thank you for your time!